# How would I add working preview and settings panel to a screensaver I made with auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, settings, preview, screensaver

I created a weird little graphic using tkinter and wanted to make it into a screensaver. I used auto-py-to-exe to convert the .py to an .exe and renamed it to .scr.

Whenever the windows screensaver window tries to get a preview on the little monitor, it runs the screensaver at full screen. Whenever the settings button is pressed, it runs the screensaver at full screen.

How would i go about adding a working settings panel (or just have something else pop up when settings is pressed) to this program? Also, if possible, how would I get the little preview to work?

I cant seem to find any documentation on how separate settings panels for applications work or how the screensaver preview is configured/created.

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

max_boxes_on_screen = 100

min_box_width = 10
max_box_width = 100

min_box_height = 10
max_box_height = 100

box_creation_delay = 30 # milliseconds


main = Tk()
main.geometry("500x500")
main.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
main.attributes("-topmost", True)
main.configure(bg="black")

collist = ["#0078ff","#bd00ff","#ff9a00","#01ff1f","#e3ff00","#ff0000"]

screen_width = main.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = main.winfo_screenheight()

def esc(event):
    global stop
    stop = True
    main.destroy()

main.bind("<Motion>", esc)
main.bind("<Key>", esc)
main.bind("<Button-1>", esc)
main.bind("<Button-2>", esc)
main.bind("<Button-3>", esc)
main.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: esc(None))
main.config(cursor="none")

cnt = 0
cnt2 = 1
stop = False
box = []
while True:
    if stop == True:
        break
    else:
        if cnt >= max_boxes_on_screen:
            box[cnt2].destroy()
            cnt2 += 1
        cnt += 1
        xx = random.randint(0, screen_width)
        yy = random.randint(0, screen_height)
        col = random.choice(collist)
        ranwid = random.randint(min_box_width,max_box_width)
        ranhig = random.randint(min_box_height,max_box_height)
        boxf = Frame(main, width = ranwid, height = ranhig, bg=col)
        box.append(boxf)
        boxf.place(x=xx, y=yy)
        main.after(box_creation_delay, main.update())
    
main.mainloop()
```

I am aware this isnt the best way to make a screensaver and that tkinter isnt really built for this kinda stuff but i still really want to figure out how to make this work.

Thank you.

Comment: 1st problem I see is you are using a `while` loop inside the `mainloop`. Never do this and never use sleep in the there either. You need to build a function that uses after to manage that while loop instead.

Comment: Also what "settings" nothing in your code refers to any kind of settings.

Comment: After reviewing your question and building something on my end I realized you need to somehow have your python executable detect when the screen saver menu has clicked Settings or Preview. I am not 100% sure if this can be done but it would be the only way to differentiate the buttons being pressed. Maybe some win32 library can detect this in python and then you simple use an if statement to run the screensaver or run a settings window.

Comment: Turns out, after some digging i found out that windows runs a screensaver with arguments dictating what the program should do. After finding what those args are i was able to get it all working, only running into another problem with windows "failing to execute script" when changing screensavers using the control panel.